# MySQL datadir space issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

```
I have 450+GB MySQL Database running on linux.
```

MySQL Version - 5.6.31

```
Daily at a certain time I can see a peculiar issue, while I use 'df -h' I can see used space is 650 GB but 'du -h' is showing 450 GB.

Can anyone please help on this?
```

Comment: `df` - free space on disk? `du` - used space on disk?

Answer (score 0):

- df is Disk Free space
- du is Disk Used

If you are expecting these to match then that is only possible if disk is 50% used.